# Swift - In App Purchase - Invalid product identifier

Tags: ios, swift, identifier, storekit

This subject of In App purchase make big headache. 
1) i did everything by the book , and im getting this error :

```
 reason: 'Invalid product identifier: (null)'
```

*The bundle id and the xcode, apple developer and itunes connect are all the same*
*the id is 100% correct*
 here is the methods i used :

The button that trigger everything :

```
let payment : SKPayment = SKPayment(product: self.product)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
```

Other methods ::

```
 func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {

        var productsarray : Array = response.products
        if productsarray.count != 0 {

            product = productsarray[0] as SKProduct


        }
        else {

            println("no products found")

        }
        productsarray = response.invalidProductIdentifiers

    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        for transaction in transactions
        {
            if transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased {
                unlockpurchaes()
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
            }
            else if transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed {
                println("transaction failed")
            }


        }
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        unlockpurchaes()
    }
```

View Did load :

```
  self.productid = "ExtraHeartbeat"

        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {

            let request : SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: NSSet(objects: self.productid))
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()

        }
        else {

            println("cannot buy")


        }
```

Properties :

```
 var product : SKProduct!
    var productid :  String!
```

Comment: Did you build the app with the correct provisioning profile that includes the in app purchase capability and matching bundle ID ?

Comment: @Zhang about the provisioning i created new one but im not sure if i implement it correctly , how can i?

Answer (score 0):

Have you completed the legal, bank and contact information? Cause for me that did the trick.

Comment: Actually i think it was itunes connect problem. and it got fixed after some time lol